# using ipywidgets in jupyter notebook: how to set focus?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Is it possible to give a jupyter notebook widget the focus? 
I can't see documentation or hints in the code about this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a [pull request](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/pull/2630) regarding this issue and in [this commit](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/commit/8b1abab31683f4a61ed468212182f6988fbd530b) you can actually see it in code. Since this PR is already merged I hope it will be out in the upcoming **[ipywidgets 8.0](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/milestone/30)**.

Answer (score 1):

It's available via `.focus()` but not to all widgets yet it seems.

See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ipywidgets.html#ipywidgets.widgets.domwidget.DOMWidget.focus